# MSTSC (Windows Remote Desktop Connection) alternatives for Windows

Tags: terminal-services

I've got an odd issue where Microsoft Terminal Services Client is sending random uppercase and lowercase junk from my magnetic card reader.  In Linux, rDesktop works just fine.  I've got no idea what's going on, but I'm pretty sure there's a bug in MSTSC and I'd just like to avoid using it (and avoid paying for an alternative that does 99 things I don't need)

*Edit* Must use RDP protocol (i.e. not VNC or some weird internet thing).

Comment: Why is it you need to use RDP?

Comment: Good question, VNC would be OK for personal use, but this is for some software I'm writing where MSTSC 6.0 screws up the keyboard input created by a mag card reader.  Already asked a question about that on ServerFault http://serverfault.com/questions/64594/magnetic-stripe-reader-over-terminal-server-has-random-uppercase-lowercase-nonsen

Comment: Peter Turner is right, that's how we fixed barcode scanning through RDP.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this Java-based RDP client

[HOBLink JWT](http://www.hobsoft.com/products/connect/jwt.jsp)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Terminals](http://www.codeplex.com/Terminals), it's a remote control tool that supports VNC, RDP, SSH, Telnet, ...

It uses the Terminal Services ActiveX Client (mstscax.dll) so I'm not sure it'll solve your issue with mstsc.

Comment: You're right about it not solving the problem, but that is a pretty awesome program that I didn't know about.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Microsoft Terminal Services Client the latest version (currently 6.0) ?
Maybe just reinstalling the [latest version](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925876) can fix the problem.

Comment: Only downvoting this because I'm angry! Sorry.

Comment: Why are you angry?

Comment: In any case, any alternative that I know uses the RDP ActiveX control, so you'll not solve your problem this way. You must attack the problem itself : why is RDP malfunctioning? Is it by any chance trying to port your magnetic card reader to the distant machine? These are the questions to ask, IMHO. I apologize if I'm wrong.

Comment: If you can answer this -> http://serverfault.com/questions/64594/magnetic-stripe-reader-over-terminal-server-has-random-uppercase-lowercase-nonsen then you get your point back!  MSTSC 6.0 is probably the problem (that's why I'm angry), it was pointed out to me by a customer and me running it confirmed the problem.  It works fine in other programs developed in house using an older Remote Desktop Protocol, but they're really old and we don't want to support them.  It also works using the latest linux rDesktop, which I thought was rdp 6.0, but I may be wrong