# Slow Remote Desktop connection mystery D to Z

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Please help me resolve this strange case, let me introduce you the scenario:

Z: Win2003 Server
X: WinXP workstation
A: WinXP workstation
B: Win7 workstation
C: Win7 workstation
D: Win7 workstation
E: Win2003 Server

A to E hosts are located in the same lan and subnet and belong to domain H
Z, X are in other LAN, belonging to domain J, connected to A-E LAN via a fiberoptic link.

Now we test remote desktop connections from LAN A-E to LAN Z-X:

A->Z Ok. No problem.
B->Z Ok. No problem.
C->Z Ok. No problem.
D->Z Very slow and unresponsive !!! <<< I need this to be fast as others !!!!
D->X Ok. No problem.
D->E->Z Ok. No problem.

Same user (administrator) is used to log into Z in every case.

On workstation D I tried with different users (admin, non admin), different IPs, and results do not change, RD is very slow.

Physical network between A-E and Z-X is:
LAN switch->Router->ISP Fiber equipment (A-E)->ISP Fiber equipment (Z-X)-> Router -> LAN switch.
All the hosts on A-E are located at the same level connected to LAN switch, same goes for hosts on LAN Z-X. Traces from A-E hosts to Z-X hosts are the same for each A-E host.

Answer (score 0):

What are the connection settings?

Do you redirect anything? Printers, files, sound, etc?

Have you tested the performance of the network? Copy a file from D to Z? And from C to Z?

Have you tried connecting from D to X to see if the problem persists?

How about from C to X?

Comment: Connection settings are the default ones for all tests.

Comment: Try changing it then. Remove all redirections, lower the color quality, etc. And what about the other questions?

Comment: I tried with all settings in lowest value to increase perfomance but there is no difference. Network perfomance is as expected. I transferred a file via FTP from Z to D and speed is about the same as from Z to C. I tried connecting via remote desktop from Z to D and it works fine.

Comment: Hum... try:  changing network cables; change network cards; reinstall mstsc; try a different program. Have you disable folder/printer redirecting too?

Comment: What other program can be used as an alternative to mstsc ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/39792/mstsc-windows-remote-desktop-connection-alternatives-for-windows

Comment: I solved this problem changing the mac address of the D network card. I changed last two hex digits from "2E" to another value I chose arbitratily in this case "AA". I am still trying to figure out the full explanation of this behaviour.